# React tree - how do I delete current node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a tutorial on react within which a tree is created.
For instance this variable is represented as a tree:

```
var tree = {
    title: "howdy",
    childNodes: [
        {title: "bobby"},
        {title: "suzie", childNodes: [
            {title: "puppy", childNodes: [
                {title: "dog house"}
            ]},
            {title: "cherry tree"}
        ]}
    ]
};
```

I want to add a button next to each node which deletes the current node and its children.

```
var TreeNode = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            visible: true
        };
    },
    handleDeleteClick: function() {
        //What should I place here?
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.state);
        var childNodes;
        var classObj;

        if (this.props.node.childNodes != null) {
            childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
                return <li key={index}><TreeNode node={node} /></li>
            });

            classObj = {
                togglable: true,
                "togglable-down": this.state.visible,
                "togglable-up": !this.state.visible
            };
        }

        var style;
        if (!this.state.visible) {
            style = {display: "none"};
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <h5 onClick={this.toggle} className={React.addons.classSet(classObj)}>
                    {this.props.node.title}

                    <span className="input-group-btn">
                        <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleDeleteClick}>
                            Delete
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </h5>

                <ul style={style}>
                    {childNodes}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    },
    toggle: function() {
        this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible});
    }
});
```

How can I do this?
For now, unfortunately, I can't use a database for the backend.(Can I maintain state without one?)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to keep the tree content not in a global variable but in the component's state. You use the component's state already for the `visible` variable, so try to add a `tree` variable similarly.

To preserve your state across page reloads you can (for now) use something like [localStorage](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) where you can save your tree object after each change (you'll have to serialize it, e.g. using `JSON.stringify`) and load it from that when you load the page (this time deserialize using `JSON.parse`).

Since you nicely abstracted TreeNode components already, you should probably create a new component (e.g. `Tree`) that does just that: store the tree, handle adding/deleting nodes, handle storage. The Tree component has one root TreeNode that gets passed the `this.state.tree` content.

```
var Tree = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            tree: // ...
        };
    },
    handleDeleteClick: function(node) {
        // do some logic here to remove `node` from whereever it occurs
        // make sure to COPY this.state.tree and modify that, not modify the
        // original object, then pass it to this.setState()
    },
    render: function() {
        return <TreeNode tree={this.state.tree} handleDeleteClick={this.handleDeleteClick} />;
    }
});
```

Pass `handleDeleteClick` down to every tree node, on button click you should call that passed down callback (`this.props.handleDeleteClick`) and pass in the node itself or some identifier for it in the first argument (see its definition above).